# How to incorporate median value into regression as an independent variable?

Tags: r, regression

I want to regress `y` on `x1` and median value of `x2`.
I use below code with package `plm`:

```
Result <- plm(y ~ x1 + median(x2,na.rm=T),data = Panel[which(!is.na(Panel$Firms)),],
              model = "random",effect = "time",index = c("Firms", "Time"))
```

But it does not work. It returns

> Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  :
>   variable lengths differ (found for 'median(MB)')

How can I incorporate median value into regression as an independent variable?

Comment: Add this variable to your data.frame prior to running the regression.

Comment: But also realize that adding a constant to your data won't change anything about your regression - you already have a constant in the intercept. Maybe look into including an `offset` instead - not sure which `plm` implementation you are using and if it allows for an `offset` term.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I use the industry median. So it is not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in firm-specific medians, an example using the `dplyr` package would be:

```
library(dplyr)
panel <- panel %>% 
group_by(Firms) %>%
mutate(median_x2 = median(x2))
```

You should then be able to run your model using the newly generated variable.

Comment: If by industry median you mean the median across all firms for each time point, use `group_by(Time)` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use `group_by (Industry, Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is given because they haven't the same **length**, so I think there's no way of doing it without use some transformation with **median**.